# Decimal field showing incorrect format

Tags: custom-field, decimal

This is a very weird situation as I have never seen such anomaly. I created three Decimal fields on an Object and the data in these fields are populated by a trigger. Everything is fine when I see these fields. However, the same fields display incorrect format when viewed using a different user. **The Commas get replaced by a Dot and vice versa**. Screenshot below:

**When I (Admin) see the record, the field behaves properly.**

[image: WHEN I SEE THE RECORD...THE FORMAT IS CORRECT.]

**When Viewed through other user - commas get replaced by dot and vice versa.**

[image: SAME FIELDS VIEWED AS A DIFFERENT USER. Commas get replaced by Dot and vice versa.]

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user's "locale" is different. Many parts of the world use commas, periods, and spaces differently inside numbers, including: `10 000 000,00`, `10.000.000,00`, and, of course, `10,000,000.00`. You can see the user's locale settings under "User Name" > My Settings > Personal > Advanced User Details. To view the United States version of numbers, set the Locale field to "English (United States)". See the [Decimal mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark) entry on Wikipedia for other various examples you may run across, depending on locale.

Comment: That makes sense @sfdcfox. I will make the changes and see the output. Thanks a lot.